# Creating a portable PHP install?

Tags: php

I would like to create a folder with a couple versions of PHP that I can start in cgi mode as needed. I use different windows machines for development and I would like to be able to move around computers without needing to install PHP on each one. Something like below

```
F:/PHP
   /5.3.2
   /5.2.8
   /5.1.0
```

Then I could just start each up as needed with something like

```
F:\php\5.3.2\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Which would allow nginx or apache to use the PHP service. This would really help to make my development environment decoupled.

Does anyone know how to create a portable PHP install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh, the php site has [zip downloads for PHP](http://windows.php.net/download/) which are ready to run.